# Split Bibliography problem

Tags: bibliographies, splitbib

I have to create a split bibliography section, one for the books and the other one for the websites. I am using `multibib` in order to get the job done.

My general compilation is `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, command prompt, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex`. I have learned that when using this package, I have to manually run `bibtex` from the second bib file; I do it through command prompt (`bibtex <prefix of the citation command in LaTeX>`).

After doing all this, I get this:
[image: I get twice the same reference!] I get twice the same reference, where I should get two different. In fact, running manually `bibtex` for my other file, I get two errors:

[image]

The biggest issue is that, when I switch both references, I still get the error!

What am I doing wrong?

This is my main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{web}{website bib}


\begin{document}
    \citepweb{Yu1996} This is a test, I don't know how it will look \citep{Ringo2016}.

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{doc}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{books}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{docud}
\end{document}
```

This is my doc.bib

```
@Misc{Ringo2016,
  author       = {Ringo},
  title        = {Biuret Test},
  howpublished = {En ligne},
  year         = {2016},
  url          = {https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv9A7.png},
}
```

And this is my docud.bib

```
@TechReport{Yu1996,
  author      = {Xiaochun Yu},
  title       = {The complex of amylose and iodine},
  institution = {University of Wisconsin},
  year        = {1996},
  type        = {resreport},
  month       = may,
  url         = {https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244335699_The_complex_of_amylose_and_iodine},
}
```

### ***I know that I have an overflow, I wil correct it later

### Edit

As suggested by @CarLaTeX, I have tried to use `biblatex` rather than `natbib` and I have followed the section for the manual. The problem now is that I don't get any bibliography!! 
[image]

My log errors are:

[image]

My main file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{essaibibsep.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is my text.\cite{Nobody06}\cite{Yu1996}
    \printbibheading
    \printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=subbibliography, 
    title={Livres}]
    \printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibliography, 
    title={En ligne}]

\end{document}
```

and my bib file (essaibibsep).

```
@online{Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }

@TechReport{Yu1996,
    author      = {Xiaochun Yu},
    title       = {The complex of amylose and iodine},
    institution = {University of Wisconsin},
    year        = {1996},
    type        = {resreport},
    month       = may,
    url         = {https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244335699_The_complex_of_amylose_and_iodine},
   }
```

I'm expecting that the cause of my problem is in "empty bibliography" but my bibliography look the same as my previous. Also, my next problem is that I need to incorporate a specific bibliography style. How should I incorporate in this my commands?

Comment: Sorry to be "that guy", but you may want to consider using`biblatex`, it offers native support for multiple bibliographies (and many other things). See sections 3.12.3 and 3.12.4 of its manual.

Comment: The biblatex solution works for me.

Comment: For the `multibib` solution you have to use `\bibliographyweb{doc}` instead of `\bibliography{doc}`

Comment: You need to run Biber rather than BibTeX for the Biblatex solution to work. Did you do that?

Comment: @Guido My problem is solved when I am using Share Latex, but when I am back to TeXstudio, I get this error: "Error: Command crashed: biber.exe "<filename>""  I looked up online (and try to change my compilation mode..) but nothing worked. Do you know how to solve this issue?